How loading routes using yaml dsl?
I am developing an application in Spring Boot 3.2.x, Spring Cloud 2023.0.0 and Apache Camel 4.4.4. I am using yaml dsl for the routes definition. The yaml files are defined in src/main/resources/routes. In the application.yml file I set the property camel.springboot.routes-include-pattern: classpath:routes/*.yaml. When I run the application from the IDE the routes are loaded correctly, but when I run the application from the .jar file it does not load them. I have looked at the .jar file inside it already contains the "routes" folder and the .yaml files.
Can someone tell me what is happening and how to fix it?

Try with 4.8.x or 4.4.5 when its released - it smells like a fat-jar classloader issue
